# adding form with globalKey inside PageView.Builder

Tags: flutter, forms, dart, pageviews

I have form and TextFromFilde inside  PageView.builder, everytime chinge page it show me this error Duplicate GlobalKey detected in widget tree.
and some time that TextFormFilde is hideing.
all problome is GlobalKey, if I delete it every thing is working perfict but text filde is unfocused in every page I had to tap agin on it to type data

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(Myapp());

class Myapp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: PageViewTest(),
    );
  }
}

class PageViewTest extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<PageViewTest> createState() => _PageViewTestState();
}

List<TextEditingController> tecList;
var _formKey;
List controller = [
  TextEditingController(),
  TextEditingController(),
  TextEditingController(),
];
List<String> _signing_hint_text = [
  'type your domain',
  'type your email',
  'type your password',
];
List<String> _signing_input_label = [
  'Domain',
  'Email',
  'Password',
];
Size mDeviceSize(BuildContext context) {
  return MediaQuery.of(context).size;
}

PageController _pageController = PageController(initialPage: 0);

class _PageViewTestState extends State<PageViewTest> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
    // _pageController = PageController();
    tecList = List.generate(3, (index) {
      return TextEditingController();
    });
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    // TODO: implement dispose

    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.all(30),
          child: PageView.builder(
              controller: _pageController,
              itemCount: 3,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return Column(
                  children: [
                    Form(
                      autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction,
                      key: _formKey,
                      child: TextFormField(
                        autofocus: true,
                        textAlign: TextAlign.right,
                        textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
                        style: TextStyle(color: Color(0xff030303)),
                        cursorColor: Color(0xff5e6593),
                        controller: tecList[index],
                        keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                          hintText: _signing_hint_text[index],
                          focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderSide: BorderSide(
                              color: Color(0xff5e6593),
                            ),
                          ),
                          contentPadding:
                              EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5.0, horizontal: 10),
                          labelText: _signing_input_label[index],
                          labelStyle: TextStyle(color: Color(0xff5e6593)),
                          floatingLabelBehavior: FloatingLabelBehavior.auto,
                          border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                          alignLabelWithHint: true,
                          hintStyle: TextStyle(
                              color: Color(0xff5e6593),
                              fontSize: 15,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.normal),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    ElevatedButton(
                        onPressed: () {
                          _pageController.nextPage(
                              duration: Duration(milliseconds: 800),
                              curve: Curves.ease);
                        },
                        child: Text('click')),
                  ],
                );
              }),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not use one `formKey` for all `Form` widgets in each page, you should define `formKey` for each page of your page view and use index to know which one is for which page. For example define three different `formKey` and use index like this:

```
List<GlobalKey<FormState>> formKeys = [GlobalKey<FormState>(),GlobalKey<FormState>(),GlobalKey<FormState>()];
```

and inside your `PageView.builder`, do this:

```
Form(
   autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction,
   key: formKeys[index],
   ...
)
```

**But** For `focus` each `TextFormField` when page change, first define a list like this:

```
List<FocusNode> focusList = [FocusNode(), FocusNode(), FocusNode()];
```

then do this inside `PageView.builder`:

```
PageView.builder(
     onPageChanged: (value) {
               FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(focusList[value]);
     },
     controller: _pageController,
     itemCount: 3,
     ...
}
```

And also do not forget to pass those `focusNode` to `TextFormField`:

```
child: TextFormField(
    focusNode: focusList[index],
    autofocus: true,
    textAlign: TextAlign.right,
    ...
)
```

Comment: sounds good
but is it has secont problem

Comment: what is the second problem? @SaiedRahimi

Comment: just like I was deleted the global Key

Comment: if I delete it every thing is working perfict but text filde is unfocused in every page I had to tap agin on it to type data

Comment: I mean when `GlobalKey` deleted and typing something in first page when go to second page and trying to type it write on first page and continuing forest textfield content

Comment: This is the wrong way to make textfield focus. @SaiedRahimi

Comment: I updated my answer, for you issue, check it out @SaiedRahimi